# Excel - как присоединить иной макрос (кроме _Click) к элементу

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Есть у меня, например, раскрывающийся список (Combo Box, не ячейка с проверкой данных).

Есть следующий код:

```
Sub DropDown_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.TopIndex > -1 Then
        Dim curIndex As Integer
        curIndex = ComboBox1.TopIndex + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Y / 13.5, 0)
        curValue = ComboBox1.List(curIndex)
        Range("G1").Value = curValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Как мне корректно присоединить эту функцию к элементу? Пробовал через 'Назначить макрос', но Эксель, похоже, думает, что через эту кнопку назначаются только события клика.
Или мне нужно заменить `DropDown` на имя элемента? Если да, то как мне получить имя элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Когда добавляете контрол есть две группы - "Элементы управления формы" и "Элементы ActiveX". Используйте ActiveX, у них события доступны.

Comment: Ясно, к сожалению элементы ActiveX доступны только в Windows.

Comment: Работаете на MAC'e? Вы бы написали, почему не принимается Проверка_данных, UserForm? Чем вызваны ограничения?